# Beginner Question: Why is this inner for loop not incrementing in JS?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if looking at code all day is making me blind, beside my natural ignorance, but I can't find out why I cannot get the inner look to throw its next item into  `finalDataset`. The intent is to generate a new array with some modifications. Appreciate any help.

```js
const arr1 = [
  ["Header1", "Color", "Size"],
  ["Data1", "Blue", 16],
  ["Data2", "Red", 20],
  ["Data3", "Brown", 5],
]
const arr2 = [
  ["Name", "CorrectedColor", "Style"],
  ["Nike", "Black", "Rock"],
  ["Puma", "Purple", "Country"],
  ["ShingLing", "White", "Romantic"],
]

let finalDataset = [];
for (let a = 1; a < arr1.length; a++) {
  let newRow = arr1[a];
  for (let n = 1; n < arr2.length; n++) {
    newRow[0] = arr2[n][1];
    newRow[1] = arr2[n][2];
    newRow[2] = '-'
    console.log(newRow)
    finalDataset.push(newRow)
  }
}
console.log(finalDataset)
```

Comment: It's not very clear as to what is expected, please post what the result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that each time through the inner loop, it's modifying on the same `newRow` array, and then pushing that one array into `finalDataset`. In the end, `finalDataset` only has 4 distinct arrays in it, where each one is repeated 4 times (once per element of `arr2`). Also, you're inadvertently modifying the elements of `arr1` through `newRow`.

As small change should give you something closer to what you're expecting, by creating a new array for `newRow` each time through the loop:

```js
const arr1 = [
  ["Header1", "Color", "Size"],
  ["Data1", "Blue", 16],
  ["Data2", "Red", 20],
  ["Data3", "Brown", 5],
]
const arr2 = [
  ["Name", "CorrectedColor", "Style"],
  ["Nike", "Black", "Rock"],
  ["Puma", "Purple", "Country"],
  ["ShingLing", "White", "Romantic"],
]

let finalDataset = [];
for (let a = 1; a < arr1.length; a++) {
  for (let n = 1; n < arr2.length; n++) {
    let newRow = [arr2[n][1], arr2[n][2], '-'];
    finalDataset.push(newRow)
  }
}
console.log(finalDataset)
```

Comment: Thank you, Ken! It helps me learn a lot...this front. Thanks!

Comment: @onit I think this is actually a better solution to your question, you should accept it instead.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde no worries, it was just a couple of minor things. Tried to get OP to accept...

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde looks like I succeeded :)

Answer (score 2):

You're pushing references to the same array into `finalDataset`, so they all take the same value (and you're changing `arr1` while you're at it - check with `console.log(arr1)` after your code completes). You can work around this by making copies of the arrays, e.g. using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) (you could also use e.g. `[...newRow]`):

```js
const arr1 = [
  ["Header1", "Color", "Size"],
  ["Data1", "Blue", 16],
  ["Data2", "Red", 20],
  ["Data3", "Brown", 5],
]
const arr2 = [
  ["Name", "CorrectedColor", "Style"],
  ["Nike", "Black", "Rock"],
  ["Puma", "Purple", "Country"],
  ["ShingLing", "White", "Romantic"],
]

let finalDataset = [];
for (let a = 1; a < arr1.length; a++) {
  let newRow = arr1[a].slice(0);
  for (let n = 1; n < arr2.length; n++) {
    newRow[0] = arr2[n][1];
    newRow[1] = arr2[n][2];
    newRow[2] = '-'
    finalDataset.push(newRow.slice(0))
  }
}
console.log(finalDataset)
```

Comment: Right on! I'm not I get why ```slice(0)``` is used in this case, but I'll verify. Thank you!

Comment: @onit slice returns a copy of the array starting from the supplied index. With `0` as a parameter it gives a copy of the entire array.

Comment: `[...newRow]` is an alternative way to produce a shallow copy of `newRow`   (alternative to `newRow.slice(0)`)

Comment: @Wyck yes, I mentioned that in my comments at the top of the answer